# what does project onto self mean?

Tags: modeling

i was watching blender gurus video about donut making and his options for snapping to face ahd less options to mine because i had "project to self" selected and it wasnt even an option for him. what does this mean and how will it effect my work?[image: blender guru blender]

[image: my blender]

Comment: it looks like he has the option as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1isb0x4zYw&t=260s

Answer (score 4):

This basically means that you can snap one element to the other inside the same object.

Example with vertex snapping:

[image]